# Angular Protractor test session persistence

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm working on e2e tests for a web app and I would like to log in a user and persist their session.

Specifically the following scenario:

1. The log in form is posted with valid credentials.
2. Angular routes the user to a landing page.
3. I call browser.get( /* the current url */ )
4. I expect the current URL to be the same, instead of my user getting kicked back to the log in screen.

We're using HTTP header based auth and I don't know how to configure this scenario for testing purposes.

Is it as simple as activating cookies somewhere? Or maybe supporting the auth headers via a config?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this be simply adding `browser.sleep(1000)` in before calling `browser.get( /* the current url */ )`.

Basically Protractor was hammering on the router to fast and my app was kicking me out before auth creds were set. Or, perhaps, might be the HTML5 routing takes a little time to process (our deep links are hashed, but then angular converts the hash to HTML5 routes).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `browser.waitForAngular();` too.

Comment: This answer turned up in the low quality review queue, presumably because you don't provide any explanation of the code. If this code answers the question, consider adding adding some text explaining the code in your answer. This way, you are far more likely to get more upvotes — and help the questioner learn something new.

Answer (score 0):

You can use promises like this

```
goAfterLogin: function(){
    browser.get('http://www.example.com').then(function(){
        return this; //or other return

    }).then(function(){
        return this;
    });
 }
```

Its up to you how will you use it (you as well can create promis with waitForAngular() )